# Jquery undefined MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am new here and i hope you can help me with my issue.

First of all i am not familiar with jQuery.

I followed a tutorial to make an autocomplete function for my Website TextBox.

But somehow i get an error for the jquery scripts saying 0x800a1391 Runtime Error in JavaScript jQuery undefinded when running the application.

I tried it with different versions of jQueryfile for autocomplete. Right now im using the latest Version included with NuGet.

Thanks for your help.

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

<div>
    <label>Markensuche</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="searchInput" />

</div>
<script>
    $("#searchInput").autocomplete{
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax8{
                url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchValue","Home")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { search: $("searchInput").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {label:item.TabakMarke,value:item.TabakMarke}

                    }))
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Debbuging Error Code

```
  <div class="container body-content">

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

<div>
    <label>Markensuche</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="searchInput" />

</div>
<script>
    $("#searchInput").autocomplete{
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax8{
                url: '/Home/GetSearchValue',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { search: $("searchInput").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {label:item.TabakMarke,value:item.TabakMarke}

                    }))
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2020 - Meine ASP.NET-Anwendung</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost:44399/fcfbda4df83942d79d121bc3bce382d4/browserLink" async="async" id="__browserLink_initializationData" data-requestId="67935583404a485d8c1f16cb2c900e1f" data-appName="Internet Explorer"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jquery-ui requires that jquery be included *first*.  Edit: actually you have jquery-ui included twice.  Why?  Edit: Make that 3 times ...

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Note the section headed "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" in the latter link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including jQuery UI, but not jQuery itself (jQuery UI does not include jQuery).

Try to include `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js` as well.